# How does Maven set application placeholder #spring.profiles.active#

Tags: jhipster

JHipster build question:

I'm trying to figure out how the JHipster Maven build sets the `#spring.profiles.active#` placeholder in the `application.yaml` file.

Is there some Maven task that does a search and replace of `#spring.profiles.active#` based on my active Maven profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by the maven-resources-plugin configured to use # delimiter, check your project's pom.xml